# How to get explicit time after selecting a date in Material UI KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, uidatepicker

When I pick the date on a calendar it returns me the needed date but with current time. Here's an example of an output after picking a random day in seven o'clock: 'Tue Dec 01 2020 19:28:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)'. I want it to return me 00:00:00, as it does when I write the date into the input by myself without picking it on the calendar.

Here's a datepicker's code snippet:

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        className="search-element"
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        format="dd/MM/yyyy"
        id="date-picker-inline"
        label="пошук від"
        value={firstDate}
        onChange={handleFirstDateChange}
        KeyboardButtonProps={{
          'aria-label': 'set first date',
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Look at DateFormatter

Comment: which date utils are you using?

Comment: I use @date-io/date-fns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material date pickers will always put the current hour seconds of your browser timezone, I have a lot of problems with that but you can always do

```
import React from "react";

export default function YourComponent() {
 const [firstDate, setFirstDate] = React.useState(null)

 const handleFirstDateChange = (date) => {
  const newDate = date;
  // Check if date is present, user can leave it as an empty field
  if (date) {
   //Set's the given date to UTC midnight (start of the day)
   newDate.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
  }
  // Set the date to your local state or where you are storing it
  setFirstDate(newDate)
 }

 return (
   <KeyboardDatePicker
    className="search-element"
    disableToolbar
    variant="inline"
    format="dd/MM/yyyy"
    id="date-picker-inline"
    label="пошук від"
    value={firstDate}
    onChange={handleFirstDateChange}
    KeyboardButtonProps={{
      'aria-label': 'set first date',
    }}
   />
 )
}
```

This will make the date to use the UTC start of the day, you can also use setHours but that one will use your browser timezone, which can be different depending on the user location.

I would also suggest to use Luxon library and luxon utils instead of date-fns if your requirements need a specific timezone(this is what I ended up doing).

Comment: Oh God, the problem with timezone is pissing me off. I need now to send 23:59:59 on backend and cause I have +2  my calendar is having display problems. When I choose 01/12 it displays 02/12 because for my browser time is 02:00:59 of 02/12 and not 23:59 of 01/12. How should I use luxon for that? It returns an object not a string. Maybe you can give an advice?

Comment: Hey with luxon you will receive a DateTime object which is a custom object off their library, they allow to modify the object a lot so for example if you want your date to be at the end of the day you should do something like date.endOf('day'), look at this: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#instance-method-endOf

Comment: But keep in mind you should also enforce a timezone if you want the app to always send the same date, for example an user with eastern time in the browser will store a different date than an user with central standard timezone, that's why if you want to enforce an specific timezone, you should modify the luxon object, check the last section of this: https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones

Comment: can you help with implementation of that method? This doesn't work: 
  `const handleStartDateChange = date => {
    const newDate = date
    if (date) {
      newDate.endOf('day').toISO();
     }
     setStartDate(newDate)
  }`

Comment: did you make all the changes to support luxon? you need to add the library plus the utils for mui pickers, if that's added I think you should be able to use it, what is the console.log(date) output?

Comment: the object as it is after first pick. So method doesn't cause an error, but also it doesn't change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226260/discussion-between-newlomter-and-jean182).